# List of all street and road names in Google in API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, gps

Am doing a location based app.When using GPS, it provides with street names from Google API. When user need to enter it manually, for a autocomplete text view am in need of names of all street and roads in Google API. Where could i get all street and roads name which google API provides when using GPS?
I ve searched everywhere but in vain :(
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can find, Google does not provide a database of street names for public download, but this site does: [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

These databases are available for free download.  They contain geographical information about the whole planet.  I hope you find them useful.

Comment: It's important to note that Open Street Map's data is not licensed under Apache or MIT licenses. They use the Open Data Commons Open Database License, which is a copy-left license which means that it requires derivative works to also be licensed under the same terms as the original work.

Answer (score 6):

The Google Places API suggests search results for city/street names etc. which you can use for an AutoCompleteTextView.

Here is a running [JS demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?hl=de) for testing the results.

Because your using Maps API V3, here is the reference to [google.maps.places.Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Autocomplete)

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android?hl=de) you can find an API for Android.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks above :) Actually I found an another way too.. the names of the streets and roads in xml returned by google api are marked as "route".. so I parsed the xml having type="route" to get only road and street names!!

Comment: please provide an example.

Comment: Please explain how you did it!

Comment: Google API [documentation] (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) mentions that **route** cannot be used in the request. It states this:

Note: The types below are not supported in the type filter of a place search, or in the types property when adding a place.