# Street and Road names in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I would like to retrieve all the road and street names, if i enters a area in search box. Is that possible in Google API ?

I have checked [List of all street and road names in Google in API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997275/list-of-all-street-and-road-names-in-google-in-api) for solution, but there it is been given for auto complete box and the request is not for my requirement.

Also I learnt that Open Street Maps provide us these data, unfortunately I would like to perform some operations based upon the Google API's. So can you suggest me a way, otherthan OSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps API does not provide such functionality. However, there is a Google Maps Roads API which is one of their premium paid APIs which lets you query nearest road names and other road metadata. You can check that out here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro

You can also try Overpass-Turbo (https://overpass-turbo.eu/) which lets you query OSM data. You can set the bounds and the OSM tags you are interested in.